# Using call_user_func_array on the db_select object

Tags: 7, database

[call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/call-user-func-array) makes calling a variable function with a set of arguments fairly simple. I would like to do the same with [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) passing in various options to different methods. Going to use dblog_cron from [6.x](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.module/function/dblog_cron/6) and [7.x](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.module/function/dblog_cron/7) as the examples. How can I do something similar in D7?

D6 Code

```
<?php
// These 2 lines return the same thing in D6
$max = db_result(db_query('SELECT MAX(wid) FROM {watchdog}'));
$max = call_user_func_array('db_result', array(call_user_func_array('db_query', array('SELECT MAX(wid) FROM {watchdog}'))));
?>
```

D7 Code

```
<?php
$min_row = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
  ->fields('w', array('wid'))
  ->orderBy('wid', 'DESC')
  ->range(999, 1)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

 // Getting closer but not what I'm looking for.
 $min_row = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
   ->{'fields'}('w', array('wid'))
   ->{'orderBy'}('wid', 'DESC')
   ->{'range'}(999, 1)
   ->{'execute'}()
   ->{'fetchField'}();
?>
```

How can I call the above code without eval using something like call_user_func_array() or [ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs](http://php.net/reflectionmethod.invokeargs)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It was a request for how to execute a query directly using HTTPRL's threading library http://drupal.org/node/1555314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking this down...

```
<?php
$x = call_user_func_array('db_select', array('watchdog', 'w'));
$x = call_user_func_array(array($x, 'fields'), array('w', array('wid')));
$x = call_user_func_array(array($x, 'orderBy'), array('wid', 'DESC'));
$x = call_user_func_array(array($x, 'range'), array(999, 1));
$x = call_user_func_array(array($x, 'execute'), array());
$min_row = call_user_func_array(array($x, 'fetchField'), array());
?>
```

In-lining everything... so it can be done.

```
<?php
$min_row = call_user_func_array(array(call_user_func_array(array(call_user_func_array(array(call_user_func_array(array(call_user_func_array(array(call_user_func_array('db_select', array('watchdog', 'w')), 'fields'), array('w', array('wid'))), 'orderBy'), array('wid', 'DESC')), 'range'), array(999, 1)), 'execute'), array()), 'fetchField'), array());
?>
```

---Solution below---

```
<?php
// Setup data array.
$args = array(
  array(
    'db_select', array(
      'watchdog', 'w',
    )
  ),
  array(
    'fields', array(
      'w', array('wid')
    )
  ),
  array(
    'orderBy', array(
      'wid', 'DESC'
    )
  ),
  array(
    'range', array(
      999, 1
    )
  ),
  array(
    'execute', array()
  ),
  array(
    'fetchField', array()
  ),
);

// Helper function.
foreach ($args as $data) {
  if (!isset($last)) {
    $last = call_user_func_array($data[0], $data[1]);
  }
  else {
    $last = call_user_func_array(array($last, $data[0]), $data[1]);
  }
}

// Get output
echo $last;
?>
```